# set /A [expression] in batch files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So, my question is following:
Why, when i write code like this in command line:

```
set /A 1+2
```

3 is displayed on the console

But, when i set up .cmd script with same code output is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the [documented](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/set.mspx) behaviour of the command

> If you run set /a from the command line outside of a command script,
>   it displays the final value of the expression